# Wifi issue after sleep

Tags: wifi, suspend, internet, init-script, sleep

I am running Linux Mint 19 Tara. I cannot understand why but lately my wifi stop working after I resume it from sleep, the only way to make it work is either a reboot or

`sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager restart`

could you help me in fixing it or implementing a script with such code that would start everytime I resume the laptop?

EDIT:

-linux mint version

-output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A 3`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

-output of `rfkill list`

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
5: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Are you sure that it is Linux Mint 19.3 ? It has not been released yet (next December or January).

2) Can you provide in your question, the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -i network -A 3` and `rfkill list` ?

**EDIT**

I'm suspecting (but I can get wrong) that it is related to the power management of your wifi card after enabling the sleeping mode.

Maybe you can try to change the `powersave` value from 3 to 2 as explained in these posts: [How to turn off Wireless power management permanently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently) and [More wifi issues - Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 ath10k_pci](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878097/more-wifi-issues-qualcomm-atheros-qca6174-ath10k-pci)

For doing that, you can check the value of the power save mode:

```
cat /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

And change the value to 2 by doing:

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Comment: it worked for two times and then it stopped working.

Comment: This does not work, this has no effect on the issue

Answer (score 0):

I was also unable to activate WIFI after resuming PC from sleep.

Always getting "Hard block: yes"

Restoring BIOS to factory defaults finally resolved the problem. Not shore what particular BIOS setting thou.

HP Pavilion 15-n004ej
RT3290 Wireless - driver=rt2800pci driverversion=5.4.0-54-generic firmware=0.37
Linux Mint 19.3
5.4.0-54-generic
wifi.powersave = 3