# How to turn off Wireless power management permanently using systemd-networkd?

Tags: linux, wifi, power-management

This question is very much related to [How to turn off Wireless power management permanently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently), albeit when using systemd-networkd to manage hardware.

I have a headless Raspberry Pi Model 3 connected to a printer whose only job it is to collect print jobs (CUPS) and forward them to the printer (using the AirPrint protocol mostly). Sometimes I cannot ping it. I suspect that the wireless card powers down after awhile. I can rule out connectivity issues because it is near an access point. Is there any way to influence this in my unit configuration? I could not find it documented anywhere.

```
wlan0.network 
[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
#Domains=local

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=20
```

And yes, I know I can do `iwconfig wlan0 power off` to disable power management on the device. I just like having static configuration files:

So I am looking for an equivalent to NetworkManager's

`/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Answer (score 6):

I ended up writing a parameterized unit configuration to do it.

/etc/systemd/system/wlan-always-on@.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Keep wireless device %i from sleeping.
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/iw %i set power_save off

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Usage

```
systemctl enable —now wlan-always-on@wlan0.service
```

Comment: The above answer by Jonathan Komar is right, just be sure to place the service file in the [right directory](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000006168/boards-and-kits.html).

Comment: Upvoted, with a mild "yuck" aimed at systemd-networkd for not yet having a better, simpler way to do this.

Comment: @ZacharyPuthoff: UNIX systems that follow the FHS (Fillesystem Hierarchy Standard) discourage local configuration changes to /lib as those files can be overwritten during system upgrades or may be mounted read-only. On Debian GNU/Linux, one would put the file in `/etc/systemd/system/wlan-always-on@.service`.