# Wi-Fi powersaving in NetworkManager

Tags: linux, wifi, networkmanager, power-management

I found this option in the file `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` :

```
wifi.powersave = 3
```

But couldn't find detailed explanations about that in the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html):

> wifi.powersave 
> If left unspecified, the default value "ignore" will be used.

I noticed that my Wi-Fi signal sometimes goes down even if the modem is near my laptop.Can that option cause this behavior ? And also does that have an impact on speed? (because of the packet drops due to low signal intensity)

And what does `3` mean in that option?

Thanks.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jcberthon/ea8cfe278998968ba7c5a95344bc8b55

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently/473753

Answer (score 0):

Possible values for the `wifi.powersave` field are:

`NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DEFAULT` (`0`): use the default value
`NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_IGNORE`  (`1`): don't touch existing setting
`NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_DISABLE` (`2`): disable powersave
`NM_SETTING_WIRELESS_POWERSAVE_ENABLE`  (`3`): enable powersave

found here:[How to turn off Wireless power management permanently](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For future reference, the appropriate action when an answer to another question on Unix.SE is relevant, is to suggest it as a duplicate, not copy the information.